# Scaling thousands of automated forecasts in R

Tags: r, scalability, forecast

Hello and thanks in advance!  I'd like some advice on a scalability issue and the best way to resolve.  I'm writing an algorithm in R to produce forecasts for several thousand entities.  One entity takes about 43 seconds to generate a forecast and upload the data to my database.  That equates to about 80+ hours for the entire set of entities and that's much too long.

I thought about running several R processes in parallel, possibly many on a few different servers, each performing forecasts for a portion of total entities.  Though that would work, is there a better way?  Can Hadoop help at all?  I have little experience with Hadoop so don't really know if it can apply.  Thanks again!

Comment: I would begin by looking at the time required to make forecasts and interacting with server times. Can they be optimized further? If not, then you should try distributed/parallel computing solutions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working with R language, I would suggest first to try use **R ecosystem**'s abilities to *parallelize* the processing, if possible. For example, take a look at packages, mentioned in [this CRAN Task View](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/HighPerformanceComputing.html).

**Alternatively**, if you're not comfortable or satisfied with the approaches, implemented by the above-referred packages, you can try some other approaches, such as Hadoop or something else. I think that a *Hadoop* solution would be an **overkill** for such problem, considering the *learning curve*, associated with it, as well as the fact that, as far as I understand, Hadoop or other MapReduce frameworks/architectures target *long-running processes* (an average task is ~ 2 hours, I read somewhere recently). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your approach is working, you can try to implement it more efficiently. Identify the crucial points, try to *vectorize* them better, for example.

The R interpreter isn't the fastest. There are some efforts underway, but they are not yet ready. Vectorization (which means less interpreter, more low-level code) often yields a factor of 2x-5x, but you can sometimes get a factor of 100x by implementing it e.g. in C. (And the R advocates are going to hate me for saying this...)
Once you know that your approach is working, this may be worth the effort.